# TDBAdvGrid does not append a record when down-arrow at last record

Tags: delphi-2007, tms

I am using TDBAdvGrid to display a database.  With other DB Grids, when one attempts to go past the EOF with the down-arrow, a new empty record is automatically appended.  This is not happening with TDBAdvGrid.  Is there some trick to getting this feature to work?

Answer (score 0):

Set Grid.Navigation.AppendOnArrowDown to TRUE...